# BIGQUERY SQL STATEMENT WHERE SAME RECORD WAS NOT NULL PREVIOUSLY BUT NULL NOW

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have table (bsr_pickpack) with two columns ie asin (STRING) and sales_rank (INTEGER) where same asin (STRING) repeats again but few repeated asin without sales_rank (null). So I tried to get a list of such repeated asin which have null sales_rank later in repeat.

```
SELECT asin,sales_rank
from bsr_pickpack
WHERE asin !='' AND (sales_rank is not null)
and asin in(
select asin from bsr_pickpack where not (sales_rank is not null)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some records with `asin` value `valueA` have their corresponding `sales_rank` value as `NULL` will get selected in the inside select clause. The, some other records with the same `asin` value `valueA` with their corresponding `sales_rank` value as not `NULL` will also match the rest of the filters, since their `valueA` will be included in the `IN` clause, but they're not the same records as the ones that passed through the inside select clause.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, this works for me :)

```
SELECT  asin,sales_rank 
from bsr_pickpack 
WHERE asin!="" 
and asin in( 
select asin from bsr_pickpack where sales_rank is null
) 
order by asin
```